# N1QL query not recognizing parameters

Tags: sql++, couchbase-java-api

I am trying to use parameterized N1QL Query but its not recognizing the  json place holders and throwing incorrect syntax exception.

**Code:**

```
public static final String LMR_DETAILS 
    = "SELECT * FROM $bucketName WHERE lmr.lmrStatusDescriptionTe ='PENDING'and STR_TO_MILLIS(lmr.recordExpirationTs) BETWEEN STR_TO_MILLIS($startTime) AND STR_TO_MILLIS($endTime)";

String bucketName = bucket.bucketManager().info().name();
                    JsonObject placeHolders = JsonObject.create().put("bucketName", bucketName).put("startTime", reqDates[0]).put("endTime", reqDates[1]);
                    N1qlQuery query = N1qlQuery.parameterized(QueryString.LMR_DETAILS, placeHolders);
                    N1qlQueryResult result = bucket.query(query);
```

Comment: bucket name after FROM clause can't be parameterized.

Answer (score 0):

After FROM clause requires as static identifier refer to bucket or subquery, It can't be parameterized variable. Remove $bucketName  as parameterized variable and replaces with actual bucket name by constructing LMR_DETAILS dynamically.

Comment: Thank you @vsr. But I have to pass Bucket Name Dynamically as I am having many Environments with different buck names. How can I do that

Comment: String LMR_DETAILS = "SELECT * FROM " + bucket.bucketManager().info().name() + "  WHERE lmr.lmrStatusDescriptionTe ='PENDING'and STR_TO_MILLIS(lmr.recordExpirationTs) BETWEEN STR_TO_MILLIS($startTime) AND STR_TO_MILLIS($endTime)";